# Docker Jenkins fails to load plugins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I ran `docker run jenkins` and Jenkins starts correctly but almost all plugins failed to install.

In the log I got errors like this one:

```
SEVERE: Failed to install Folders
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install cloudbees-folder plugin
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Folders Plugin v6.11.1 failed to load.
 - You must update Jenkins from v2.60.3 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My bad, I was using the wrong image - it should be `docker pull jenkins/jenkins` instead of `docker pull jenkins`. I found the answer in https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/787 and https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/12/10/the-official-Docker-image/#official-jenkins-image-to-use-from-docker-hub.

Comment: Thanks you..!  The only solution that works well